# Clear textboxes when SelectedIndex == null

Tags: c#, .net

Im writing stock program - just to learn a little bit of c# and i got some problem.

Here is a part of mine code

```
    private void comboBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string conString =
         "Data Source=192.168.0.195;" +
         "Initial Catalog=test;" +
         "User id=sa;" +
         "Password=12345678;";

        string query = "Select * from dokumenty where symbol='" + comboBox_symbol.Text + "' ;   ";
        SqlConnection conDB = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand cmdDB = new SqlCommand(query, conDB);
        SqlDataReader sqlReader;

        try
        {
            conDB.Open();
            sqlReader = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                var s_Typ_dok = sqlReader.GetString(1);
                var s_Symbol = sqlReader.GetString(2);
                var s_Delivery_date = sqlReader.GetString(3);
                var s_Invoice_date = sqlReader.GetString(4);
                var s_Invoice_nr = sqlReader.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                var s_Sybtype = sqlReader.GetString(6);
                var s_Produkt_index = sqlReader.GetString(7);
                var s_Produkt_name = sqlReader.GetString(8);
                var s_Quantity = sqlReader.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                var s_Price = sqlReader.GetString(10);
                var s_From_warehouse = sqlReader.GetString(12);
                var s_To_warehouse = sqlReader.GetString(13);
                var s_Currency = sqlReader.GetString(14);
                var s_Supplier_reciever = sqlReader.GetString(15);

                comboBox_Type.Text = s_Typ_dok;
                textBox_symbol.Text = s_Symbol;
                textBox_deliveryDate.Text = s_Delivery_date;
                textBox_invoiceDate.Text = s_Invoice_date;
                textBox_invoice.Text = s_Invoice_nr;
                textBox_subtype.Text = s_Sybtype;
                textBox_produkt_index.Text = s_Produkt_index;
                textBox_name.Text = s_Produkt_name;
                textBox_quantity.Text = s_Quantity;
                textBox_price.Text = s_Price;
                comboBox_from_warehouse.Text = s_From_warehouse;
                comboBox_to_warehouse.Text = s_To_warehouse;
                comboBox_currency.Text = s_Currency;
                textBox_supplier.Text = s_Supplier_reciever;    

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

which works ok, when i selected something in combobox5 it auto insert things to Textboxes when it exist in DB, but when i erase this thing which i select in combobox5, text in textboxes is still there. Is there any chance to erase it when combobox5 == null?

Comment: How do you fill the combo? What is the value for the DropDownStyle property of the combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `SelectedIndexChanged`  event add one condition to check SelectedIndex==0, if selected index is zero then clear text of Text box,

If you don't wants to edit text from combo box then you can set combobox as non editable by setting

```
comboBox5.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

This will not allow user to edit text from combobox

```
private void comboBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(comboBox5.SelectedIndex==0)
      {
          TextBoxId.Text=String.Empty;
      }
      else
      {
         //Rest of your code here
      }
}
```

Comment: Can describe exact scenario why this didnt work for you?

Comment: It just doesn't clear textBox when i errase text in combobox.

Comment: When you are editing text in combobox in that  case your event will not get fired, thats why this will not clear text when you are erasing text

Comment: Thanks a lot, i just set non editable combobox and then add one empty item to this and when its empty im just clearing TextBoxes